# Closure of $ A:=\bigcup_n\gamma_{n}^{-1}(\infty)$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\gamma_n:\overline{\Bbb C}\to\overline{\Bbb C}$ a sequence of continuous mappings such that
$$
\gamma_n^{-1}(\infty)\subset \gamma_{n+1}^{-1}(\infty)\;\;\forall n\in\Bbb N\;.
$$

Consider
$$
A:=\bigcup_n\gamma_{n}^{-1}(\infty)\;.
$$

Then $A$ is the set of all points $y\in\overline{\Bbb C}$ for which $\exists N$ such that
$$
\gamma_n(y)=\infty\;\;\forall n\ge N\;.
$$
How can I prove that the closure of $A$ (in $\overline{\Bbb C}$) consists of all the points $y\in\overline{\Bbb C}$ such that
$$
\lim_{n}\gamma_n(y)=\infty\;\;?
$$

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Does $\bar{\mathbb{C}}$ mean the Riemann sphere?

Comment: This looks quite false.

Comment: Indeed it is not true even for $f_n(z) = z+n$ (and $f_n(\infty) = \infty$).

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$\gamma_n(z)=\begin{cases}\frac1{4\pi^2n}\lvert z\rvert^2&\text{if }\lvert z\rvert>2n\pi\\ n\sec^2\lvert z\rvert&\text{if }\lvert z\rvert\le 2n\pi\end{cases}$$

(where I've imposed $\lvert\infty\rvert^2=\infty$ and $\sec^2\left(k+\frac\pi2\right)=\infty$ for all $k\in\Bbb Z$).

Then $\gamma_n^{-1}(\infty)=\{\infty\}\cup\bigcup_{k=0}^{2n-1}\left\{z\in\Bbb C\,:\, \lvert z\rvert=k\pi+\frac\pi2\right\}$, and therefore $A$ is the closed set $$A=\{\infty\}\cup\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb N}\left\{z\in\Bbb C\,:\, \lvert z\rvert=k\pi+\frac\pi2\right\}$$ but $\lim_{n\to\infty}\gamma_n(z)=\infty$ for all $z\in\overline {\Bbb C}$.